# PHP warning scandir /var/lib/mysql/ - CENT'OS - need scan files of database

Tags: centos

Need make zip arc of files from /var/lib/mysql/admin_d1_com/ catalog.

> PHP warning scandir(/var/lib/mysql/admin_d1_com/): failed to open dir:
>   Permission denied
>   /var/www/html/splitter3000/protected/extensions/EZip.php(68)
>   I've done:

1. User "Apache" has been adedd to groupe "mysql" - nope
2. Demon Apache has been started as root - nope

Sory for My Eng. (I'm from UA)

Answer (score 0):

> The default UMASK and UMASK_DIR values are 0640 and 0750, respectively
>   (0660 and 0700 prior to MySQL 5.7.6). MySQL assumes that the value for
>   UMASK or UMASK_DIR is in octal if it starts with a zero. For example,
>   setting UMASK=0600 is equivalent to UMASK=384 because 0600 octal is
>   384 decimal.

### I'm need to set default creation file perm. in 0750 at my way it is 0777 and add user to group to mysql.

> Adding backup user to mysql group:
>   usermod -a -G mysql backup
>
> ### > chmod g+rx /mysql/data -R
>
> vi /etc/init.d/mysqld 
>   UMASK=0640
>   export UMASK
>   UMASK_DIR=0750
>   export UMASK_DIR

[src](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/umask-umask_dir-changing-mysql-file-dir-permissions), [src2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/environment-variables.html)